# For Loop- putting range into list doesnt work for me

Tags: list, for-loop, range

learning For Loops now and going through so many different resources. Found thi snice YT video, but completely stuck on 4:49mintue of the video, I am trying to re-run the code myself but getting error in my colab cell, while guy on video isnt (putting range into list with small brackets?!)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnDr4J2UXSA

```
c = list(range(1, 5))
print(c)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-524f9deb9e59> in <module>()
      1 # 1, 2, 3, 4
---> 2 c = list(range(1, 5))
      3 print(c)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

any idea please? thanks a lot!
```

Comment: Is that the exact code you're running? It works for me. Did you accidentally declare a variable called list?

Comment: Yes completely! Such a basic mistake of a beginner. Thanks a lot Tyler!